# TimeMe.js store data to databse

Tags: javascript

I'm using [TimeMe.js](https://github.com/jasonzissman/TimeMe.js) to track time spent on page.

Is there any way to auto save time spent on the page to database table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TimeMe.js  library doesn't provide an auto save feature, but it provides a web socket reporting option. Then you can use the reports your receive through the web socket connection to save them to a database. Check it [here](https://github.com/jasonzissman/TimeMe.js#what-do-i-do-with-the-time-ive-tracked).

Comment: Ok, noted. Is it possible to store data in a log file ?

Comment: TimeMe.js doesn't supply any means to store data. If you look at the API you can find different possibilities to get info about the current status. Saving that info is more up to you.

Comment: I can't figure it out ... Any help please to create a simple web socket to retrive data ?

Comment: I have tested this feature with this library for node js https://github.com/websockets/ws it works for sure. Just start a server like in their github page. I suggest you do this locally first and then you can just point the timeme to the server you created with the right port.